# How to initialize routes from an array in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I want to initialize routes for every region stored in a separate array:

```
regions: any[] = [
    { cityEng: 'moscow', cityRus: 'Москва', region: 'Моск', value: 'Москва и МО', isTop: true },
    { cityEng: 'Saint-Petersburg', cityRus: 'Санкт-Петербург', region: 'Санкт-Петербург', value: 'Санкт-Петербург и ЛО', isTop: true },
    { cityEng: 'Novosibirsk', cityRus: 'Новосибирск', region: 'Новосибирская', value: 'Новосибирская обл.' }
];
```

if I create a route NOT from an array like:

```
var routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [MetaGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./components/main-page/main-page.module').then(m => m.MainPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'moscow',
    canActivateChild: [MetaGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./components/news/news.module').then(m => m.NewsModule)
  }
];
```

it works.

However, If I insert a route object with exactly the same properties, it will give me 404 error...

```
var routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [MetaGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./components/main-page/main-page.module').then(m => m.MainPageModule)
  }
];

regions.forEach(region => {
  var regionRoute = {
    pathMatch: "full",
    path: region.cityEng.toLowerCase(), 
    loadChildren: () => import('./components/main-page/main-page.module').then(m => m.MainPageModule),
    data: { region: region }
  };

  routes.push(regionRoute);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because of **404** route (path: '**')  that MUST BE THE LAST ONE in your list of routes!
Hope it helps anyone

```
  // !!! HAS TO BE THE LAST ONE
  // Show the 404 page for any routes that don't exist 
  {
    path: '**', canActivateChild: [MetaGuard], 
    loadChildren: () => import('./not-found/not-found.module').then(m => m.NotFoundModule)
  }
```